# How to create linked (associated) automatically updated form fields in GAE Django

Tags: django, forms, google-app-engine, choicefield

I am new to Django and GAE. I would like to create two input fields, where the first one is a drop-down menu (let name it select), which decides the values in the second one (let name it val).

For example, once 'A' is chosen from 'select', field 'val' will show '1'. similarly, 'B' is associated to '10'. I have written several lines below, but it does not work. Two issues:

1. The second field ('val') always equals 0.
2. It seems like my second field ('val') does not 'listen' to the choice made by the first one ('select'), which means those two fields are not linked.
   Can anyone give me some suggestions (or recommend books on using Django on GAE)? Thank you!

   ```
   select_CHOICES=(('A','A'),('B','B'),('Other','Other'))
   select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=select_CHOICES, initial='A')

   def get_choices(select):
       if select=='A':
           r= 1
       elif select=='B':
           r= 10
       else:
           r= 0
       return r

   val=forms.FloatField(initial=get_choices(select))
   ```

Comment: You should try to make the post a bit clearer. It also contains multiple typos in the code. Also it's good practice to have variable names (Select) start with lowercase letter.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have understood how django works a bit wrong. The code that you input is run before the page is rendered, so no selection is made yet. If you want the input field to dynamically change as user makes the choise on page, you should use Javascript.

Also you are comparing a Field (select) to a string ('A'), which naturally always is unequal.

Read more documentation and tutorials and you'll soon get how it works.

Comment: @thong Don't know what you mean by instance refresh feature. And yes, you should add the Javascript to the template.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I mean instantly update field value without refreshing webpage.

Comment: is there a way to compare a Field (select) to a string ('A')? Thanks!